# node ws package, seperate connections into rooms

Tags: node.js, typescript, ws

I am trying to create a "rooms" like feature with the npm 'ws' package, similar to how rooms work in socket.io. I dont want to use socket.io, but cant figure out how to get information on the user/room at connection without sending an extra message.

I took this from the ws docs and it allows me to iterate through all the clients, but i would like to also differentiate a room?

```js
import WebSocket, { WebSocketServer } from 'ws';

const wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 8080 });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  // would like to add a user to a room here?
  ws.on('message', function message(data) {
    wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
      if (client !== ws && client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
        // only send to clients in the same room
      }
    });
  });
});
```

This is the client side I have been using to test:

```js
import WebSocket from 'ws';

const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');

ws.on('open', function open() {
  ws.send(JSON.stringify({roomId: 1}));
});

ws.on('message', function message(data) {
  console.log('received: %s', data);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to assign a room at connection you change the path of the url and then access it through the `req` object, then add it as a property on the connecting websocket.

Then you can send the roomId with any message and check that the roomId for message and the roomId for the client match before sending.

```js
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws, req) {
  ws.roomId = req.url;
  ws.on('message', function message(data) {
    const parsedMessage = JSON.parse(data);
    wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
      if (client !== ws && client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
        if(client.roomId === parsedMessage.roomId){
          ws.send(data);
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

In order to connect to this socket you would have to change your client to send to the url + the roomId.

```
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/<put room id here>');
```

Without sending a second message this appears to get the functionality you are looking for